# How do I crop and display a specific tile of a texture sheet, using a HLSL shader?

Tags: shader, directx, hlsl

I have a 96x96 texture sheet made up by 32x32 sized tiles. Using a shader I am looking to display only 1 tile at a time. I am completely lost on how to properly do it however.  The code I've cobbled together below appears to grab the top-left pixel of the map...

```
sampler2D atlas : register(s2);

int texHeight = 96;
int texWidth = 96;
int tileSize = 32;
int tileFrame = 1;

float4 ps_main(in float2 In : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0 {

float4 atlasColor = tex2D(atlas, float2( (In.x*tileSize)+tileFrame,(In.y*tileSize)+(floor(tileFrame)/texWidth)));

return atlasColor;

}

technique tech_main { pass P0 { PixelShader = compile ps_2_a ps_main(); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the values coming in via `TEXCOORD0` are from `0.0` to `1.0`.

When sampling a texture, values from 0.0 to 1.0 will read one complete repeat of the texture. Since you're using integers, you are multiplying your U and V coordinate by 32, so you are asking for 32 repeats of the texture.

With another assumption that you might have a texture with mipmaps, drawing this in a smallish region of your render target will force the hardware to read the smallest mip, which would give you one color.

Instead, you need to multiply In by the *fraction* of the texture that you want to see, i.e. `tileSize/texWidth` and `tileSize/texHeight`, i.e. `1/3`.

You also need to break down the `tileFrame` into the column and row for which frame you want to sample. The *column* needs to produce `0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2`, and your *row* needs to produce `0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2`.

The code to do that is:

```
float column = tileFrame % (texWidth / tileSize); // i.e. 3
float row = tileFrame / (texHeight / tileSize); // i.e. 3
```

`%` returns the remainder of dividing `tileFrame` by `3`.

A note on that code; `tileFrame` should start from `0` for the first tile.

Using the column and row to produce an offset into the texture uses the same fraction we used to scale the `In` texture coordinates;

```
// This has a problem, see below
float2 offset = float2(column * (tileSize/texWidth), row * (tileSize/texHeight));
```

*But there's an extra wrinkle* we need to deal with; `tileSize`, `texWidth` and `texHeight` are all integers, so the result of these divisions is also going to be integers, so when we ask for `tileSize / texWidth`, which is `32 / 96`, we are not going to get `0.3333`, but `0`, because 96 does not divide *even once* into 32.

To fix that we need:

```
float2 offset = float2(column * (tileSize/(float)texWidth), row * (tileSize/(float)texHeight));
```

BUT, this is all smoke and mirrors; since texture coordinates are between 0 and 1, and **not** in pixels, the *dimensions* of your texture are not important, only the number of tiles across and down. We don't need to know the dimensions of the texture, nor how big a tile is. We only need the number of rows and columns.

Here's my version:

```
sampler2D atlas : register(s2);

int columns = 3;
int rows = 3;
int tileFrame = 1;

float4 ps_main(in float2 In : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0 {

  float2 tileSize = float2(1.0 / columns, 1.0 / rows);
  float2 tileXY = float2(tileFrame % columns, tileFrame / rows);

  // Scale texture coordinates and add offset.
  float2 tileUV = In * tileSize + tileXY * tileSize;
  // Easier to understand than
  // (In + tileXY) * tileSize

  float4 atlasColor = tex2D(atlas, tileUV);

  return atlasColor;
}

technique tech_main { pass P0 { PixelShader = compile ps_2_a ps_main(); } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I am not only being helped with the code but actually learning a lot. Your approach also makes a lot more sense.  

I ran into a strange issue that I cannot figure out though. I even double-checked by testing the exact code of what you posted, just to be sure.  

Basically not all frames work..

1st column = tileFrame value
2nd column = Corresponding tile being displayed  

`0=0,
1=1,
2=2,
3=3,
4=3,
5=4,
6=6,
7=6,
8=7`  

So #3 and 6 shows up twice while #5 and 8 are skipped entirely... Could it be some some rounding issue?